# Reboot always redirects to initramfs shell

Tags: command-line, reboot

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on `Dell PowerEdge 2800 RAID Controller 4e/Di` (with 6 hard drives, I chosed RAID5).
I encrypted the disks using LUKS (cryptsetup).
After installation, each time I reboot the `initramfs shell` prompts.
Why does this happen ?
More precisely, during the installation process, Ubuntu displayed a message which states that `No hard drive found. If you know the necessary driver for the functioning of your hard drive, select it from below`. I do not know which driver to select, so I tried the items one after the other until one of them is accepted.
on the initramfs shell, `ls` shows only these directories/files:

```
lvm, udev, console-setup, nsswitch.conf mtab,<br>
`modprobe.d fonts, passwd` and `default`
```

`ls` and `lspci` give me this (screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Try taking out 5 Disks out of the Array, Formatting one, then reinstalling.  Afterwards Go into the RAID setup tool, turn on the option to not reinitialize disks after new installs, and reinstall the 5 other disks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initramfs shell is a very low level system, basically a ramdisk with very low level kernel functions, it is NOT loading your drives so whatever `ls` shows you is not indicative of what is on your hardrives

You need to tell linux what driver to use for your RAID controller in order to install properly, RAID contollers are very unstandardized with often no overlap in functionality or drivers between manufacturers, just picking randomly is not an optimum strategy because it will probably break something.

A quick google search tells me you will most likely need to select the MegaRAID driver from the list for this card (it supports all Dell PERC 4 cards). You will need to reinstall.

Comment: Thank you but MegaRaid is not accepted (I tried it at least twice last week)

Comment: I also tried it right now, a moment ago, but it does not accept it as a driver for my HDDs.

Comment: @begueradj Could you boot into a live-cd and run `lspci` and post the output in your question?

Comment: @begueradj you are sure that the RAID is enabled in BIOS and that low level RAID utility (`ctrl-m` on boot) is configured properly?

Comment: Yes, I enabled the RAID from the BIOS as it must be done. Now I restarted the machine and I am waiting ...

Comment: I can not boot from a live CD (I am using Server edition of Ubuntu). It prompts me to the initramfs shell again. NB: at the start, it asks me to boot from the first HDD, I choose it. Otherwise it offers me normal installation.

Comment: @begueradj you are right, I forgot that server doesnt have a livecd option. Instead, start the installation, after choosing the language select "go back" to get to the install menu and then select the install step "execute a shell" and then run `lspci` and post the output

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such option after I choose the language. No way to execute the command aparently.

Comment: @begueradj Make sure to click "go back" or press `ESC` after selecting the language (if you want english, which is default, then you can just click `ESC` as soon as the installer starts)

Comment: @begueradj Yes as an edit to your question, if it is very long, you can place it in pastebin and link to it in your question

Comment: I edited my question. You can see the output of ls and lspci.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14338/discussion-between-crasic-and-begueradj)

Comment: I did the second solution you proposed me last night (install on 1 HDD, upgrade kernel and migrate). It worked :) ! No I can sleep and I thank you a lot for your help.